# Getting "Error during sync. Timeout." error on android CTS (Compatibility Test Suite)

Tags: android, testing, compatibility, cts, suite

**Problem:**  When I try to run my a complete test on CTS on the ubuntu command line "run cts --plan CTS", I get the error message "Error during sync. Timeout."

**Additional Information:**

- I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.0 LTS on the VirtualBox.
- the host Operating System is Windows 7 Professional.
- The device I'm running CTS on is physically connected to a USB 3.0 Port.

**Tried (and failed) Solutions:**

*Solution 1:* I tried restarting both the host OS and Ubuntu after getting  the "Error during sync. Timeout." message

*Solution 2:* I connected the device physically to a USB 2.0 Port

*Solution 3:* Used a different wire to connect my computer to the device.

*Solution 4:* Shutdown the device and turned it back on after getting the "Error during sync. Timeout." message.

*Solution 5:* I restarted the adb server by typing "adb kill-server" and then typing "adb devices"

Note that throughout all the solutions above, I made sure that the Guest OS in the VirtualBox can recognizes the plugged in USB device.  I did this by:

- Typing in "lsusb" in the command line
- Typing "adb devices" in the command line.
- Checked that "USB Debugging" option is checked under the Developer Options in the device.

Any answers is greatly appreciated!  If there's any information I forgot to bring up, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Update (Solution Below)**

I know I'm answering my own question but whatever, hopefully someone else can get help from my post.

I fixed this issue by not using VirtualBox at all! I found an old PC no one uses and I installed Ubuntu 12.04.0 LTS there by burning the iso file (which contains the Ubuntu OS) into a DVD.

From the old PC, I installed adb, fastboot, and CTS and I was able to run a successful test!

I know that my solution is expensive as it requires another PC, I suppose being able to boot another OS (Ubuntu 12.04.0 LTS) is just as good.  I think the underlying problem is using VirtualBox (or any virtualization machine).